# Show that lamda is greater than or equal to zero for a sturm liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

To show that this problem can be put into S-L form for an eigenvalue problem,

Observe that

The S-L form is of $$\text{p'(x)}\phi _x\text{+p(x)}\phi _{\text{xx}}\text{+q(x)$\phi $+$\lambda \phi $w(x)=0}$$

And multiplying the equation by $$1/x$$, we have

$$\text{x$\phi $''+$\phi $'+}\text{$\lambda $x}^{-1}\text{$\phi $=0}$$

we have that $$p'(x)=1,p(x)=x,q(x)=0 and w(x)=1/x$$

How do I show that $$\lambda \geq 0$$? Am I to invoke Rayleight's quotient?

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$
           x\phi''(x)+\phi'(x)+\frac{\lambda}{x}\phi(x) = 0
$$
can be written as
$$
              -(x\phi'(x))' =\frac{\lambda}{x}\phi(x)
$$
Now suppose that $\phi$ is a solution of the above for which $\phi(1)=\phi(2)=0$. Then
$$
       \lambda\int_{1}^{2}\phi(x)^{2}\frac{1}{x}dx
    = -\int_{1}^{2}(x\phi'(x))'\phi(x)dx \\
    = \left\{ -(x\phi'(x))\phi(x)|_{x=1}^{2}+\int_{1}^{2}x\phi'(x)\phi'(x)dx\right\} \\
    = \int_{1}^{2}x\phi'(x)^{2}dx.
$$
If $\phi$ is not identically $0$, then
$$
           \lambda = \frac{\int_{1}^{2}x\phi'(x)^{2}dx}{\int_{1}^{2}\phi(x)^{2}\frac{1}{x}dx} \ge 0.
$$
In fact, the equality is strict because if $\lambda = 0$, then $\phi'\equiv 0$ and, hence, $\phi\equiv C$ which forces $C=0$ because $\phi(1)=\phi(2)=0$. Therefore $\lambda > 0$.

**The Eigenfunctions and Eigenvalues:** The original ODE is Euler's equation
$$
                     x^{2}\phi''(x)+x\phi'(x)+\lambda\phi(x)=0.
$$
The solutions for $\lambda > 0$ are of the form $x^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ satisfies
$$
                       \alpha(\alpha-1)+\alpha+\lambda = 0,\\
                           \alpha^{2}=-\lambda \\
                                \alpha = \pm i\sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
The eigenfunctions $\phi_{\lambda}=Ax^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}+Bx^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}}$ require $\lambda$ to satisfy
$$
        \phi_{\lambda}(1)=A+B = 0 \implies A=-B \\
        \phi_{\lambda}(2)=A2^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}-A2^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}}=0
           \implies 2^{2i\sqrt{\lambda}}=1
$$
So the eigenvalues are the $\lambda$ for which
$$
                     e^{2i\ln(2)\sqrt{\lambda}}=1 \\
           \implies 2\ln(2)\sqrt{\lambda} = 2\pi n,\;\;\;n=1,2,3,\cdot \\
                 \implies \lambda = \frac{\pi^{2}n^{2}}{\ln(2)^{2}}
$$
Substituting back into the expression for $\phi_{\lambda}$ above, the eigenfunctions are non-zero constant multiples of
$$
   \phi_{n}(x) = \sin\left(n\pi\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}\right),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You shoud subsitute in formla then show that every term is equal or grater than zero

Comment: It is problematic to solve for $$\phi$$.